# Newline in error_log() in PHP

Tags: php

How can I insert a newline while using `error_log()` in PHP?

I tried to use `<br>` and `\n`, but those didn't work.

Comment: I wouldn’t do that. I would expect that every line in the error log is one single entry. Spreading a message over two or more lines would break this.

Comment: Until PHP provides better tools for logging and retrieving errors besides just dumping them to error_log, this is not a realistic expectation.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use double quotes when adding the error message.

```
error_log("This is a two lined message. \nThis is line two.");
```

should work.

```
error_log('This is a one lined message. \nThis is the same line still.');
```

will not work: notice the single quotes.

Comment: You haven't given the 2nd and 3rd parameter(the name of the error log file )

Comment: So? The other parameters are optional. Maybe you should specify what you want to achieve, because AFAICT you've just been given the solution to your problem.

Comment: @Satish, sorry for the late comment, but, if we do not put any second and third parameter, the log gets written to php's default error log file: 'php_errors.log' which is welcome.

Comment: @Koks_rs: try `\r\n` in MS Windows?

Comment: This solution doesn't account for situations where the log entry is being composed by `join`.

Comment: @JayBienvenu that might be because, 12 years ago, OP didn't ask anything about join in their question?

Answer (score 36):

[PHP_EOL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol) manages newlines on multiple platforms:

```
error_log("Error message" . PHP_EOL, 3, 'error.log');
```

Comment: Nice one, works fine with PHP running on IIS. \10 didn't work but this one does.

Comment: Good answer, but I'd suggest the other order: print each new error message on a new line: `error_log(PHP_EOL."Error message", 3, 'error.log');`

Answer (score 35):

As mentioned before, you can use either `PHP_EOL` or use double quotes in order to output a newline to your log file.

Anyway, when using the Linux console in order to debug the application, the [`tail`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)) command will show the new line as `\\\\n`.

A simple solution is to use `sed` in order to replace `\\\\n` with `\\n`:

```
tail -f file | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

See this answer: *[Display \n characters as newlines when using tail?](https://serverfault.com/questions/126407/display-n-characters-as-newlines-when-using-tail/126409#126409)*

Comment: and how to use it with grep ?

Comment: This is actually proof that error_log is not outputting newline characters properly.  tail doesn't auto escape anything.  This was the only thing that solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

I occasionally run into this problem, but certain PHP interpreters don't always play fair with `\n` on their own.  My ugly solution requires adding the raw ASCII code for newline, `\10`, seems to do the trick.  So try `\n\10`:

```
error_log("\n\10\n\10" . $this->db->last_query() . "\n\10\n\10");
```

It's miserable looking code, so you might want to wrap this into your own function... but it makes the error log look a lot better if you want something to stand out.

I also have no clue why this works better...

Comment: Re *"certain PHP interpreters don't always play fair with \n"*: Couldn't it be fault of the shell in use ([Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell), [CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe), [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), [C shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell), etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

If your error log path is undefined in both your `php.ini` file and your function call, then `\n` and `\r\n` won't work, even when double quoted (they'll show up as literal characters instead).

You can fix that by either specifying a location in `php.ini`:

```
error_log = /var/log/php-errors.log
```

Or in each PHP function call like this:

```php
error_log("error message", 3, $logFileLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

When debugging, if you want to make your error log line stand out while you're watching the log 'tail -f', I use a little function like this to make the line stand out and be easily readable.

Just throw in some white space, and a common term like 'CUSTOM_LOG' for later [grepping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) purposes.

```
highlight_error_log('Msg here');

function highlight_error_log($str){
    error_log('CUSTOM_LOG:            ' . $str . '            ');
}
```